# javascript add keypress (enter) to on()function as event listenner

Tags: jquery, keypress

I have a JS script

```
$(".cartItem-discount").on('focusout', '.cartItemPromoCode', function(){    ..... }
```

How can I fire event on focusout + keypress 13 (enter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event.which](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) like this:

```
$(".cartItem-discount").on('focusout keypress mouseleave', '.cartItemPromoCode', function(e){
   if(e.which == 13 || e.type == 'mouseleave'){
    //do something
  }
});
```

Comment: yah it works for keypress. but focusout won't fire if code is inside in if condition

Comment: enter button is keypress event not focusout. How can you focusout while pressing enter key?

Comment: I mean how can you determine when you focusout the keypress event?

Comment: ok i will mark this one. it works by adding function inside and outside of if condition.

Comment: technically my event fires when mouse leave and press enter, thats why focus out and keypress 13